# Node.js/express parsing data and still getting back [object Object] in response and some data is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, express

As stated above I am using NODE/Express backend and trying to parse out some data before I send it to the front-end.

I have an array of objects(items) and want to parse out a certain field in each item, particularly the `description` and the `geolocation`. It seems like it works just fine, but I have a couple of issues I am running into.

First I will show you one of the items to show you what it was before:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59925302e12872a81b28099e"
    },
    "offer": "19f5d9ef37b30311",
    "txid": "389eb024f8869d787954c74d1653b8358e581cb4c81358361ffac662875bceec",
    "expires_in": 13770133,
    "expires_on": 1516531809,
    "expired": false,
    "height": "46411",
    "category": "for sale",
    "title": "Jack Garratt Signed Deluxe CD",
    "quantity": "1",
    "currency": "USD",
    "sysprice": 415240000000,
    "price": "35.00",
    "ismine": false,
    "commission": "0",
    "offerlink": "false",
    "private": "No",
    "paymentoptions": 2,
    "paymentoptions_display": "BTC",
    "alias_peg": "sysrates.peg",
    "description": "{\"description\":\"Signed, near mint double CD Only played a very few times\",\"media\":{\"defaultIdx\": 0,\"mediaVault\": [{\"mediaType\":\"img\",\"mediaURL\":\"http://i.imgur.com/bB7QjDR.jpg\"}]}}",
    "alias": "Signed, near mint double CD Only played a very few times http://i.imgur.com/bB7QjDR.jpg",
    "address": "1GR389Tki2LS3jScFUhrVxVnXdPdED5839",
    "alias_rating_display": "0.0/5 (0 Votes)",
    "offers_sold": 0,
    "geolocation": "{\"coords\":{\"lat\":36.8518706,\"lng\":-123.5029326}}",
    "alias_rating_count": 0,
    "alias_rating": 0,
    "safetylevel": 0,
    "safesearch": "Yes",
    "offerlink_seller": "",
    "offerlink_guid": "",
    "time": {
        "$date": "1970-01-18T04:29:58.326Z"
    },
    "cert": "",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Next I will show you how I parse the data I want. I particularly want a `description` `geolocation` and a new field `media`.

```
  let newResults = [];
  let updatedItem = {};
  results.map((item, i) => {
    const newDescription = JSON.parse(item.description);
    const newGeolocation = JSON.parse(item.geolocation);
    console.log(newGeolocation)
    updatedItem = item;
    updatedItem.geolocation = newGeolocation;
    updatedItem.media = newDescription.media;
    updatedItem.description = newDescription.description;

    newResults.push(updatedItem);

    return newResults;
  });

  console.log(newResults[24]);
```

Here is the result of `console.log(newResults[24])`:

```
{ _id: 59925302e12872a81b2809a3,
  offer: '17fff08820c6da06',
  txid: 'f27ec82c4cd694ecfdf061ebff7709a6154e39767595f7da08e4b2a40503c816',
  expires_in: 26828208,
  expires_on: 1529589884,
  expired: false,
  height: '276435',
  category: 'for sale',
  title: 'Marijuana Flavoured Vape E-Liquid 10ml 6mg',
  quantity: '19',
  currency: 'GBP',
  sysprice: 1912000000,
  price: '2.00',
  ismine: false,
  commission: '0',
  offerlink: 'false',
  private: 'No',
  paymentoptions: 1,
  paymentoptions_display: 'SYS',
  alias_peg: 'sysrates.peg',
  description: 'Marijuana Flavoured E-Liquid 10ml 6mg',
  alias: 'Marijuana Flavoured E-Liquid 10ml 6mg',
  address: '1DNeg3CrRFx6PuLcCry26p9y2XiTzTTFqw',
  alias_rating_display: '0.0/5 (0 Votes)',
  __v: 0,
  offers_sold: 0,
  geolocation: '[object Object]',
  alias_rating_count: 0,
  alias_rating: 0,
  safetylevel: 0,
  safesearch: 'Yes',
  offerlink_seller: '',
  offerlink_guid: '',
  time: Sun Jan 18 1970 02:32:37 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time),
  cert: '' }
```

As you can see the data seems to have been parsed for the description, but the geolocation is giving me a weird `[object Object]` even though if I console log it inside the map it gives me each of the parsed data and they look fine.

Something else that I want to note here is that the media field is not even there. But if I were to `console.log(newResults[24].media)` it shows me the parsed data. But if I do try to access it on the front end like `item.media` I get undefined which is expected since it does not show up.

Comment: I noticed that you are using `.map` but you are not using its return value (which looks to be just an array of `newResults` arrays). The way I see it, you could `return updatedItem` in each map iteration and then assign `newResults` to the mapped array. This may not be the core of your issue but it will make the code cleaner and/or easier to follow. Thanks!

Comment: I did that to clean it up thanks for that helper. Still need help solving the issue however.

Comment: what defines `newGeolocation`? it is clearly doing so incorrecty

Comment: `JSON.parse(item.geolocation)` is what defines it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing `map()`.  `map()` will return an object out of it.  Try using something like this:

```
let newResults = results.map((item, i) => {
    const {
        media,
        description
    } = JSON.parse(item.description);

    const geolocation = JSON.parse(item.geolocation);

    return {
        geolocation,
        media,
        description
    };
});

console.log(newResults[24]);
```

If you want to tack these properties onto the item (without mutating the original item) you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which will dump all the properties of the objects from the second argument onward into whatever the first argument is with priority given to later arguments.

In other words, we are going to return the value returned by the call to `Object.assign({}, item, {...new props...})` and that call is going to create a new Object `{}` then dump all the properties from `item` into that new Object and then it is going to dump all the properties from `{...new props...}` on that first `{}` argument and will overwrite properties if they are already there.

```
let newResults = results.map((item, i) => {
    const {
        media,
        description
    } = JSON.parse(item.description);

    const geolocation = JSON.parse(item.geolocation);

    return Object.assign({}, item, {
        geolocation,
        media,
        description
    });
});
```

Additionally, when printing nested objects in node.js with `console.log()`, node will truncate the output rather than printing the whole arrary.  Consider this code:

```
let tmp = [
    {
        foo: "Bar",
        fizz: [
            {
                buzz: "hello"
            }
        ]
    }
];

console.log(tmp);
```

Will print:

```
[ { foo: 'Bar', fizz: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

The object is still fine, and if you try to dereference the nested object itself with `console.log(tmp[0].fizz[0].buzz);` You will get the output: `hello`.

Comment: This does work however I still need all the other fields from the previous original item.

Comment: I am getting some weird functionality. It has now the original fields and this at the end:

`pres: { save: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
 _posts: { save: [] },
 save: { [Function] numAsyncPres: 0 },
 geolocation: { coords: { lat: 46.6117304, lng: -121.8207893 } },
 media: { defaultIdx: 0, mediaVault: [ [Object] ] },
 description: 'Marijuana Flavoured E-Liquid 10ml 6mg' }`

Comment: Its like it didn't override them.

Comment: What do you mean?  If you are asking why you are seeing "`[Object]`", see my new edit.

Comment: No no. I mean I am getting back the `full original item` and then at the end of the item it now has all of the updated fields at the end, but with a `_pres` and `_posts` and `save` field right before the updated fields that we added. They didn't replace the other ones. Although I am more than positive this is how you would do this so I have no clue.

Comment: @TaylorAustin I'm really not sure where those fields are coming from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155034/discussion-between-taylor-austin-and-zero298).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
results.map((item, i) => {
  const newDescription = JSON.parse(item.description);
  const newGeolocation = JSON.parse(item.geolocation);
  console.log(newDescription.media)
  updatedItem = item;
  updatedItem.geolocation = item.geolocation; //just assign geolocation
  updatedItem.media = JSON.stringify(newDescription.media); //stringify the media object
  updatedItem.description = newDescription.description;

  newResults.push(updatedItem);

  return newResults;
});
```

Comment: the `media` field still does not show up and I need `geolocation` to be parsed so this does not work.